# gradle replace class file into modifying the MANIFEST

Tags: jar, gradle

Is possible to replace class files into a jar keeping the MANIFEST file with Gradle?
I need to do it to apply a patch from the vendor that give me only the class files.

Id tried this:

task applayPatch(type: Jar) {

```
destinationDir = new File("${rootProject.projectDir}/libs/tool") 
archiveName = "myfile.jar"

from(zipTree("${rootProject.projectDir}/libs/myfile.jar")) { 
    exclude "com/tool/frontoffice/partymanager/partysearch/DynamicPartySearchWidget.class"
}

from ("${rootProject.projectDir}/point-release/FFO-33758/com/fineos/frontoffice/partymanager/partysearch") { 
    include "MyClass.class"


}
```

}

but didn't work giving me a jar with an empty MANIFEST and only the class MyClass.class

Answer (score 3):

Try using a task of type `Zip` instead of `Jar` to avoid having Gradle generate a new manifest for you.

```
task patchedJar(type: Zip, dependsOn: jar) {
    extension 'jar'
    from(zipTree(jar.archivePath)) {
        exclude '**/MyClass.class'
    }
    from("patches/dir") {
        include 'com/foo/package/MyClass.class'
    }
}
```

Take note that by default this puts the resulting jar in `build/distributions`. Simply change the `destinationDir` property if you would like the output somewhere else.